# DataAdapter query error :"Internal error, invalid pane configuration"

Tags: .net, dataset, odp.net

When adding a parameterized query to my dataAdapter and trying to execute it, I get this exception:

> "Internal error, invalid pane configuration"

the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Expr1
FROM   SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE  (COLUMN = :PARAM1)
```

The connection string (app.config):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectName.My.MySettings.ConnectionString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=dataSourceName;PASSWORD=password;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=userId"
        providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" /

</connectionStrings>
```

Everything is supposed to work fine, we only changed the old oledb connection for this odp one to support oracle 11g.
Have you ever experienced such a puzzle? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is an issue with the Dataset... I was trying to test the query on the editor, but for some reasons, it won't work. To test it, just right click on the query, and choose preview, it should work. It is that bad... Avoid dataset if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Using  Parameterized TableAdapters creates a parameter type default as 'Object'  change it to  the type you want ie String, Number, Varchar2 ,etc. from the property window for parameter.

Comment: Can you provide an example?